# Confusion in between 'Repository' and 'Buisness Layer'

Tags: repository-pattern

It's a dummy project and mainly I want to focus on the 'Layered Architecture'. I followed this architecture from somewhere else. Here I want to bring some 'Post' from the database. so this is my Repository:

```
public class PostRepo
{
    private DataAccessLayer.DBPost _DbPostInstance = null;
    public List<ModelLayer.PostModel> ListOfPosts = null;
    public PostRepo()
    {
        _DbPostInstance = new DBPost();
    }
    public List<ModelLayer.PostModel> GetListOfPost()
    {
        DataTable dtPost = _DbPostInstance.GetPostDataTable();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtPost.Rows)
        {
            ModelLayer.PostModel postModel = new PostModel();
            postModel.id = (int)dr[0];
            postModel.postTitle = (string)dr[1];
            postModel.postBody = (string)dr[2];

            ListOfPosts.Add(postModel);
        }

        return ListOfPosts;
    }
}
```

and here goes my Buisness Layer:

```
class PostBiz
{
    private RepositoryLayer.PostRepo _postRepo;

    public PostBiz()
    {
        _postRepo = new RepositoryLayer.PostRepo();
    }

    public List<ModelLayer.PostModel> GetListOfPost()
    {
        return _postRepo.GetListOfPost();
    }
}
```

Now my question are:

1. Am I doing totally wrong?
2. If my procedure is okay, then why I am doing this? What is the main purpose and role of 'Business Layer' over here and what are the advantages I going to get by creating such Business Layer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is a best practice in other languages, but in PHP I'm using a lot of Action Domain Responder Modeling as an Architecture. This way the database is 100% abstracted away from my controller and view logic. It looks a bit like you described.

Whenever I want to add a cli script or an API based on business logic, I use the domain instead of the database. This way you don't repeat yourself and you can focus on the business logic instead of how to display or handle input and output.

In a controller where to render html, I only focus on the request and the response. The rest is abstracted away. 
In a CLI script, again I focus on input and output and call the same business logic. 
In an API, again I focus on input and output and call the same business logic.

This way, whenever business logic should change, all 3 endpoints (html, api and cli) are covered.